# What is the acronym for a minor in a subject at a university?

Tags: single-word-requests, acronyms

I'm filling out a resume and need to list my education.  For my bachelor's degree, it's just "B.S. Whatever", no problem.

I also have a minor.  What is the acronym that I should use for this?

Comment: In general, nobody except you cares about your minor. It's not a degree, so I don't expect there to be a commonly-used abbreviation for it.

Comment: @Marthaa -- ouch.  I did not know that.

Comment: Marthaª is being unnecessarily harsh; employers care about your minor if it's relevant to the position for which you are applying, or (possibly) if it's cross-disciplinary in an interesting or unusual way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your minor is relevant to the job you're applying for, [this site](http://www.ehow.com/how_8166019_list-minor-resume.html) recommends this format:

> B.Sc. Psychohistory; Minor: Library Science

There is no acronym or abbreviation necessary.

Comment: this is how I have done it on my resume

Answer (score 4):

I have seen it written (more than once) as:

> B. Sc. in Somethingorother, with a Minor in Somethingelse.

so I'd consider it correct, without any special acronym.